Self relation in C#
I have a class called Person that has an attribute called friends from which is a list of type Person. Actually, I am going to create a many-to-many relationship between the Person class and itself.
How can you create a special table for this relationship in SQL Server using EntityFramework and Codefirst (It is preferable not to use Fluent API)?
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Friends { get; set; }
}

I tried Codefirst, but the table for many-to-many relationships in the SQL Server database was not created. The only thing that happened was creating a column in SQL Server called Person_ID. It seems to create only a one-to-one relationship.
SQL Server Datatable of Person:



ID
Name
Person_ID




NULL
NULL
NULL




Which version of Entity Framework is it using?

@AndrewMorton EF6

You could try assigning a default value for the Friends property (public List<Person> Friends { get; set; } = [];). Also, can you please try using Fluent API (just to test if it works)?

@SNBS Unfortunately, it did not work. Regarding Fluent API, I must say that I want to make sure that Codefirst does not have the ability to do this and then go to Fluent API because I want the code to be as simple as possible and avoid creating complexity.

A few things you could try: define the Friends property as virtual (I know that only enables lazy loading, but it's good practice to try everything that comes to mind when something doesn't work); replace List<Person> with ICollection<Person>; decorate the property with [InverseProperty("Friends")].

Have you tested this? https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

@Oliver The issue you mentioned is correct and we need to create a special table for many-to-many relationship (Self relation) using Fluent API to solve the problem. thanks for your help.

Remember that there's no first-class way to model a symmetric relationship in a relational database.  So if Alice and Bob are friends, you need to store both (Alice,Bob) and (Bob,Alice) in the Friendship table.  Otherwise you will find Bob under Alice's friends, but won't find Alice under Bob's friends.
But to the original question,  you collection navigation properties will create 1-many relationships by default.  You must configure the entity if you want many-to-many.  It's not mandatory to have collection navigation properties for both directions.
So something like:
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Person> Friends { get; } = new List<Person>();
}

configured like
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Friends)
            .WithMany()
            .UsingEntity(t => t.ToTable("Friendship"));
    }



So, we conclude that what I want cannot be implemented with Codefirst and the Fluent API should be used. Of course you used EFCore while I'm going to use EF, although I think the code you provided shouldn't be too different from its EF counterpart. anyway, thank you for your help.
